# Required device capabilities for iPhone 5S (arm64)

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I want to require that an app is only installed on iPhone 5S. I thought that I could just put arm64 under Required device capabilities in the info.Plist file but when I do that, Xcode won't allow the app to be run on an iPhone 5S.

The instructions for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3 don't mention iPhone 5S or arm64.

Does anybody know whether an app with arm64 listed in Required device capabilities should run on an iPhone 5S?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but perhaps you can try compiling it only with arm64 architecture?

Comment: Xcode complains if I don't include armv7 along with 64 bit architecture.

Comment: Just something to consider: perhaps Apple doesn't want developers deploying apps *only* for iPhone 5S? Try to find some info on that, perhaps on the developer forums. There really isn't anything other devices can't do except the Touch ID, and that is off-limits to developers anyway. So trying to restrict an app to iPhone 5S seems like unnecessarily excluding other devices for no good reason.

Comment: There IS some functionally that is restricted to the iPhone 5S such as the M7 motion co-processor chip. That is the only sensor which is completely unique to the 5S and that is what my app requires, so that is why I want to make it run only on iPhone 5S.

Do you think Apple might reject my app if it requires hardware which is only present in the 5S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait a next month. Will release a new XCode with more powerful supporting of 32/64 bit.

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=9162013a

Comment: Cool. I missed that news from Apple. As long as they don't reject my app I can wait until next month to make it require 64-bit. I just hope they don't reject it since it can be downloaded on all iOS7 devices but only functions properly on the newest hardware. I don't want to wait a month to release it.